# Angular2 - Compile to AOT using absolute path in component templateUrl

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I am using Angular2 and pre-compiling code using AOT.

I am able to compile code when I am using relative path in Component's templateUrl.

But compilation is failing when using absolute path in component's templateUrl

Compilation command: `"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json`

I am getting below error while using absolute templateUrl:

> Error: Compilation failed. Resource file not found: {Absolute htmlUrl
>   path}
>       at ModuleResolutionHostAdapter.readResource (C:\Dipendra\stash-workspace\angular2Aot\WebContent\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\compiler_host.js:291:19)
>       at CompilerHost.loadResource (C:\Dipendra\stash-workspace\angular2Aot\WebContent\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\compiler_host.js:230:85)
>       at Object.get (C:\Dipendra\stash-workspace\angular2Aot\WebContent\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:26374:111)
>       at DirectiveNormalizer._fetch (C:\Dipendra\stash-workspace\angular2Aot\WebContent\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13753:47)
>       at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateAsync (C:\Dipendra\stash-workspace\angular2Aot\WebContent\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13799:25)
>       at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate (C:\Dipendra\stash-workspace\angular2Aot\WebContent\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13771:48)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._loadDirectiveMetadata (C:\Dipendra\stash-workspace\angular2Aot\WebContent\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18074:79)
>       at C:\Dipendra\stash-workspace\angular2Aot\WebContent\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18250:58
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.loadNgModuleDirectiveAndPipeMetadata (C:\Dipendra\stash-workspace\angular2Aot\WebContent\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18249:45)
>   Compilation failed

Answer (score 1):

Angular AOT compiler requires the template files to be in the SAME folder as the component, even though this is not required with the JIT compiler.

It was an incredibly bad decision on the part of the designers. The answer is to redesign your entire application so that the template files are in the same folder as the component.

There are several supposed work arounds, but I am not clear if they really work. I will update this post if I am successful.